# Updating logged in user's page when on other pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have a site that a user can sign up and build up their own profile page. This is done by creating a post when the user signs up, all the form data that is filled in is then saved to that post into the various custom fields. So essentially, every user has 1 post with all their profile data in.

Each user can see other people's profiles

I'm using the plugin http://www.advancedcustomfields.com and specifically using it's front end form capability.

When on the user's own profile, using the front end form capability, I can show a relationship field (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/), that then allows people to select other user's profile to essentially become a friend. This works great.

**The problem I have is when a user goes to another person's profile, there is a "become a friend" button, when clicked, I want it to add that user's page to the current logged in users relationship field. Firstly, can that be done? If so, how?**

Here's how I'm currently updating the relationship field when the logged in users on their own page (so they can add people).

```
                    <?php               
                        $activity_information = array(
                        'post_id' => $post->ID, // post id to get field groups from and save data to
                        'field_groups' => array(58), // this will find the field groups for this post (post ID's of the acf post objects)
                        'form_attributes' => array( // attributes will be added to the form element
                        'class' => ''
                        ),
                        'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() ), // return url
                        'html_field_open' => '<div>', // field wrapper open
                        'html_field_close' => '</div>', // field wrapper close
                        'html_before_fields' => '', // html inside form before fields
                        'html_after_fields' => '', // html inside form after fields
                        'submit_value' => 'Update', // value for submit field
                        'updated_message' => '', // default updated message. Can be false to show no message
                        );
                    ?>              
                    <?php acf_form( $activity_information ); ?>
```

Comment: You can put this logic in a function and call the function from the front-end via AJAX on the 'become a friend' button click.

Comment: @dalbaeb Is it possible for a code example? I wouldn't know where to start.